# Text is clickable outside

Tags: html, css

Hello I have the following structure and `Hello World` is outside of the text clickable on the right side.

It has something to do with the `display: block;` but I need that part of a code. How can I fix that?

```css
#footer-text {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section id="">
    <div class="">
        <div>
            <a href="" id="footer-text">Hello World</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You set the display of the anchor to block. What did you think it would do? If you don't know why you need it, remove it

Comment: Your anchor is sized to take up the available horizontal space. You say you need 'block' but you don't say why. There are other layout methods available that may suit your needs better such as css grid or flex-box.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `display` property's block value instructs the browser to render the element as a rectangular box that automatically expands to take up the full width available in its parent container.

To limit the width of a block-level element while keeping the `block` display property, use `max-width: fit-content` to ensure the element does not exceed the width of its content.

```css
#footer-text {
    display: block;
    max-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<section id="">
    <div class="">
        <div>
            <a href="" id="footer-text">Hello World</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I love you George thanks!!